# Disable (click) for element inside division - Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular/typescript for my web development project.

I'm looking for an efficient way to apply `(click)` event to only a division and not some selective elements inside it.

For example, consider the division :

```
<div class='card' (click)="card_click()">
    <button (click)="whatever($event)">Save</button>
</div>
```

Here, click on button will call both the functions.

It is very common to catch the event in the function and call `event.stopPropagation()` and stop the propagation.

But in special cases like a drop-down (consider following image) this thing can become tricky.

[image: example div]

I can use event of the card to check target of the mouse click to acheive the same.

I wouldn't call this the most efficient approach, but it still works.

HTML :

```
<div class='card' (click)="card_click($event)">
    <button (click)="whatever($event)">Save</button>
</div>
```

Typescript :

```
card_click(event) {

    //dropdown button catches SPAN or A
    if(event.target.tagName == "SPAN" || event.target.tagName == "A") {
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
    //do the rest
}
```

I will not prefer this solution because every time i add a new element on the card, I will have to edit this function.

Is there any other *neat* solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: `(click)="card_click(); event.stopPropagation()"`

Comment: You can add a click event listener in the capture phase and in the `event` object if the `target` is same as the dropdown don't call `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: I have edited my question to provide more details on the same

Comment: If you treat the `div` element as a `button`, ask yourself: does it truly make sense to nest a button inside of another? can this layout be changed in any form?

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Did you use my solution for this? If not please post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the target in various manners, one is to use `contains`. like this `e.target.classList.contains("innerElement")`

Then call `stopPropagation()` on the "innerElement" click event only.

So you can use a class name like "prevent-bubble" where you need it and not have to change your function every time.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jh9dpe

Comment: I'm already using this (refer to my question). This is however, not possible on drop downs, etc, where click events are not registered.

Comment: Sorry i updated the answer to show a check on the target before calling `stopPropagation()`